# Can not access IIS hosted api from real IP

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I am really novice in IIS related task.so I am facing a problem that i can not solve I tried different solutions from the internet but unable to solve it. Let me describe what i tried .
I created an api which I hosted in IIS and I can access this from my local server using the IP address .but i have a real IP of that server so that i can access the hosted API from external server or any device but when i replace the real Ip with the local Ip I can not access the api for example the real Ip is like below.
I tried the url

```
113.240.113.132 refused to connect.

113.240.113.132 is the real Ip OF 192.166.100.1

I Tried  using this ..
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":12105:113.240.113.132" />
```

with the real IP of the local IP

By using the local IP `192.166.100.1` I can access The API ,But When I Use the real IP  `113.240.113.132` i can not access the api from my browser or any device .Help Needed

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings on the server? Is 80 port opened?

Comment: its already open for the local IP, and the real Ip i have that is for the local IP ,do I open the port for this real IP also??? @CodeFuller

Comment: Firewall could bypass it rules for requests from localhost. I'd suggest adding plain html file (e.g. `test.html`) to IIS root and trying accessing it remotely. Also make sure IIS is listening on *:80 (i.e. any IP address).

Comment: Find a computer networking book to learn how those IP addresses work. Before knowing the basics, you won't easily understand what to do.